# Leading zeros lost from teradata when copied into excel

Tags: excel, teradata

So my cast function here puts leading zeros on my column called ndc11…however (which is great because I need it to be 11 digits), when I copy and paste it into excel, it looses the leading zeros. Any way to turn this also into TEXT format so that it doesn’t lose the formatting in excel?

```
select extract(month from pf.fill_sold_dt ), Cast((Cast(ndc11 As Integer) (Format '9(11)')) As varChar(11) )    , generic_prod_id,prod_name, drug_type_cd, sum(fill_qty_dspn) as Pills,  sum((fill_qty_dspn)/(pkg_sz*pkg_qty) )as Packs
from 
        prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sold pf 
inner join 
        prdedwvwh.drug_cur d
on
        pf.drug_id = d.drug_id
where 
fill_sold_dt between '2014-05-01' and '2015-04-30' and 
generic_prod_id in ( '62100005008540','62100005008530','62100005008520')

group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: You can connect to your Teradata database from Excel, and then run the query inside the table's Edit Query dialog. That way all yoiur formatting will be maintained. I use Excel as much as SQL Assistant to develop SQL. Here's a post I wrote with some info: http://yoursumbuddy.com/tables-edit-query-dialog/

Comment: That's a good point, I have done that as well, may be a good work around.

Answer (score 1):

Format the column as Text before the data goes in and then Paste Special -> Values

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm wondering how to do! How do I insert that into my cast function?

Comment: Before you paste it into Excel, highlight the column and format it as Text. Then instead of a simple Paste, right-click on the first cell and choose Paste Special. Then choose Values

Comment: What application are you copying from?  When you right-click and Paste Special, are you prompted with another dialog box with options for "Unicode Text" and "Text"?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate a single apostrophe ' at the start of the 11-digit number. Excel will then treat it as text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store those values as text (thereby losing ability to operate with them).
Use a Custom format, with 11 zeroes, [see this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/81518).

1. On the Format menu, click Cells.
2. Click the Number tab.
3. Click Custom.
4. In the Type box, type the custom format.
5. Click OK.